# MySQL Select - Merge rows when number

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, row

I would like to show results in one row and separated by column for specific values.

```
mysql> +----------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+---------------------+
    -> | temp_series_id | CO    | DP    | BO    | DZ    | KT    | KR    | DR    | GZ    | GP    | PD    | CD   | date                |
    -> +----------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+---------------------+
    -> |         272138 | 21.12 |  NULL |  NULL |  NULL |  NULL |  NULL |  NULL |  NULL |  NULL |  NULL | NULL | 2017-08-20 14:06:46 |
    -> |         272138 |  NULL | 20.06 |  NULL |  NULL |  NULL |  NULL |  NULL |  NULL |  NULL |  NULL | NULL | 2017-08-20 14:06:46 |
    -> |         272138 |  NULL |  NULL | 18.69 |  NULL |  NULL |  NULL |  NULL |  NULL |  NULL |  NULL | NULL | 2017-08-20 14:06:46 |
    -> |         272138 |  NULL |  NULL |  NULL | 21.81 |  NULL |  NULL |  NULL |  NULL |  NULL |  NULL | NULL | 2017-08-20 14:06:46 |
    -> |         272138 |  NULL |  NULL |  NULL |  NULL | 22.06 |  NULL |  NULL |  NULL |  NULL |  NULL | NULL | 2017-08-20 14:06:46 |
    -> |         272138 |  NULL |  NULL |  NULL |  NULL |  NULL | 22.44 |  NULL |  NULL |  NULL |  NULL | NULL | 2017-08-20 14:06:46 |
    -> |         272138 |  NULL |  NULL |  NULL |  NULL |  NULL |  NULL | 14.69 |  NULL |  NULL |  NULL | NULL | 2017-08-20 14:06:46 |
    -> |         272138 |  NULL |  NULL |  NULL |  NULL |  NULL |  NULL |  NULL | 24.69 |  NULL |  NULL | NULL | 2017-08-20 14:06:46 |
    -> |         272138 |  NULL |  NULL |  NULL |  NULL |  NULL |  NULL |  NULL |  NULL | 22.75 |  NULL | NULL | 2017-08-20 14:06:46 |
    -> |         272138 |  NULL |  NULL |  NULL |  NULL |  NULL |  NULL |  NULL |  NULL |  NULL | 19.94 | NULL | 2017-08-20 14:06:46 |
    -> |         272138 |  NULL |  NULL |  NULL |  NULL |  NULL |  NULL |  NULL |  NULL |  NULL |  NULL | 24.5 | 2017-08-20 14:06:46 |
    -> +----------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+---------------------+
```

How can I merge this rows to one? Something like `group by temp_series_id` and delete null values

```
SELECT
  SQL_NO_CACHE
  temp_series_id,
  CASE WHEN temp_details_id = 1 THEN value END AS 'CO',
  ...
  CASE WHEN temp_details_id = 11 THEN value END AS 'CD',
  date
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM temp_series
      ORDER BY date DESC
      LIMIT 1)
     series INNER JOIN temp_object objects ON series.id = objects.temp_series_id
  INNER JOIN temp_details details ON details.id = objects.temp_details_id;
```

Below you can see result which I would like to do

```
+----------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+---------------------+
| temp_series_id | CO    | DP    | BO    | DZ    | KT    | KR    | DR    | GZ    | GP    | PD    | CD   | date                |
+----------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+---------------------+
|         272138 | 21.12 | 20.06 | 18.69 | 21.81 | 22.06 | 22.44 | 14.69 | 24.69 | 22.75 | 19.94 | 24.5 | 2017-08-20 14:06:46 |
+----------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+---------------------+
```

Comment: suggest reading about 'pivot table'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aggregation:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE
       temp_series_id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN temp_details_id = 1 THEN value END) AS CO,
       ...
       MAX(CASE WHEN temp_details_id = 11 THEN value END) AS CD,
       date
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM temp_series
      ORDER BY date DESC
      LIMIT 1
     ) series INNER JOIN
     temp_object objects
     ON series.id = objects.temp_series_id INNER JOIN
     temp_details details
     ON details.id = objects.temp_details_id
GROUP BY temp_series_id, date;
```